# Date Range Picker - IsInvalidDate / IsCustomDate

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

I currently am using DateRangePicker by http://www.daterangepicker.com and have the following code for my project :

```
<form name="calform" action="res_info.php">
<div>Checkout<input type="text" name="checkout"/></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
isInvalidDate: function(date) {
    if (date.format('YYYY-M-D') == '2017-11-12') {
        return true; 
    }
}
    $('input[name="checkout"]').daterangepicker({
        singleDatePicker: true,
        "locale": {
        format: 'YYYY-M-D'
  }
    }, 
    function(start, end, label) {
        var years = moment().diff(start, 'years');
    });
    $('.calendar.right').show();
});
</script>
   <div> <input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
</form>
```

But for some reason , `isInvalidDate` function doesn't work at all. Please Help.

Comment: Where or how are you trying to use the function `isInvalidDate`?

Answer (score 8):

isInvalidDate appears to be a method of `daterangepicker`. As your code currently goes, that method is outside of scope of the `daterangepicker` object/function.

You'll need to place it inside  like so:

```
$('input[name="checkout"]').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    "locale": {
        format: 'YYYY-M-D'
    },
    isInvalidDate: function(date) {
        if (date.format('YYYY-M-D') == '2017-11-12') {
            return true; 
        }
    }
});
```

Additionally, it looks like the code will still be malformed. You have a, what i would consider random, function in the `daterangepicker` object. I'd read the documentation, to get a better understanding of the use of that function.

http://www.daterangepicker.com/#options

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: Thank you @Samuel !

Comment: how to use isCustomDate and apply css stile?